# Django datetime expression

Tags: python, django, datetime

Hello I am using django and am collecting datetime via

```
start_date = models.DateTimeField('start date', blank=True)
end_date = models.DateTimeField('end date', blank=True)
```

I have a report start date and a report end date.

I wish to retrieve the time taken for the report by,

taking the end_date and subtracting the end date and rounding it to the nearest day

```
def report_days(self):
    return self.end_date - self.start_date
```

currently the python shell returns this

```
>>> a.report_days()
datetime.timedelta(2, 65020, 613435)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django represents DateTimeFields as Python datetime objects, so the result of your subtraction is a `datetime.timedelta` object.  To get the number of full days, you can do:

```
delta = self.end_date - self.pub_date
return delta.days
```

This only counts full days, though.  To round to the nearest full day, you can do something like:

```
delta = self.end_date - self.pub_date
if delta.seconds / 3600 >= 12:
    return delta.days + 1 # round up
else:
    return delta.days # round down
```

For more information, see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Comment: would return self.end_date.days() - self.pub_date.days() work?

Comment: no, because the datetime object itself doesn't have a `days()` method.  If you insist on a oneliner, you can do `(self.end_date - self.pub_date).days()`